# How to change number of "colums" on diameter of a radial FacetGrid

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I change the number of months that are shown on belows circle? I would need to have december overlap with january
The code produces the figure shown below but it also throws an error (which doesn't bother me as the figure is there), maybe this is a clue.

Thanks for helping, best answer will be marked.

I have following MinRepExample:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {'month': ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'],
        'value':['4.9','4.8','4.7','4.6','4.4','4.4','4.3','4.4','4.5','4.6','4.7','4.8']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['month','value'])
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, subplot_kws=dict(projection='polar'), despine=False, height=6)
g.map(sns.lineplot(x="month", y="value", data=df ,sort=False, estimator=None))
```

I also get following error when running with Jupyter:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9e2f3dc0d427> in <module>
      6 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['month','value'])
      7 g = sns.FacetGrid(df, subplot_kws=dict(projection='polar'), despine=False, height=6)
----> 8 g.map(sns.lineplot(x="month", y="value", data=df ,sort=False, estimator=None))
      9 
     10 

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in map(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    760 
    761             # Draw the plot
--> 762             self._facet_plot(func, ax, plot_args, kwargs)
    763 
    764         # Finalize the annotations and layout

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in _facet_plot(self, func, ax, plot_args, plot_kwargs)
    844 
    845         # Draw the plot
--> 846         func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)
    847 
    848         # Sort out the supporting information

TypeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object is not callable
```

I get following output:

[image: radial FacetGrid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'month': ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dez'],
        'value':['4.9','4.8','4.7','4.6','4.4','4.4','4.3','4.4','4.5','4.6','4.7','4.8']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['month','value'])

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(df.index*np.pi/6, df.value.astype(float))
ax.set_thetagrids(range(0, 360, 30), df.month)
ax.set_rlim(4, 5)
```

[image]

If Dec shall overlap with Jan use:

```
ax.plot(df.index*2*np.pi/11, df.value.astype(float))
ax.set_thetagrids(np.arange(0, 360, 360/11), df.month)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you're the best. Not only have you given me the solution to my problem but you showed me that there is no way around learning matplotlib and this might the much more important answer :)

Comment: I'm glad you liked my answer and it was helpful :)

Comment: I use multiple years (part of df) and thus generate multiple lines, is there a way I can assign each of them a new color from a colormap? In seaborn this was easily done with hue, in pyplot I would use `colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,int(len(df.year))))`
but in the way you proposed I plot all lines simultaneously and thus can not iterate through `color`

Comment: you can plot multiple times with different colors onto the same `ax`.